# JS React: error of this.x is not a function, even when this.x function is bound

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update to update the `window` state whenever the App component mounts. With the below code, I receive an `Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: this.addTabs is not a function`.

I don't understand why this.addTabs is not considered a function, as the function is above the reference to this.addTabs(tabs), and I think it was correctly bound.

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     window: []
  };
  this.addTabs = this.addTabs.bind(this);
}

addTabs(tabs){
  this.setState({window:this.state.window.concat(tabs)});
};

componentDidMount(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
    this.addTabs(tabs);
});
```

I'm not looking to use the arrow function. I looked at similar questions, and the response was to bind the function in the constructor, which I believe I did. Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: If you dont use arrow function, you are actually referring to the function context when you use ‘this.addTabs(tabs), otherway is to you can define ‘_this = this’ inside componentDidMount and use _this.addTabs

Comment: Thanks @AaminKhan - that solved it. I should probably read up on JS function context. Cheers

Comment: Cheers my friend, happy hacking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is in this block:

```
componentDidMount(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
    this.addTabs(tabs);
  });
}
```

Inside your callback, the context is different so `this` refers to another context.

You have several ways to fix it.

1) Assign the ref to this outside the callback and use that ref:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const that = this;
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
    that.addTabs(tabs);
  });
}
```

2) Bind the current this to the callback:

```
componentDidMount(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true},(function(tabs){
    this.addTabs(tabs);
  }).bind(this));
}
```

3) Use an arrow function:

```
componentDidMount(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, (tabs) => {
    this.addTabs(tabs);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Super helpful